# 'Type Error: Not implemented for this type' when trying to make a Scatter plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, raspberry-pi, arduino-uno

This is my first matplotlib program, so sorry in advance if this seems like a dumb question.

I'm trying to setup a basic serial connection between an Arduino and a Raspberry Pi.  I was planning on starting off with something simple, like sending numbers from the RPI to the Arduino board, having it calculate something (squaring it in my case) and sending back the numbers so the RPi could plot the values individually.

Here is my Arduino code:

```
void setup(){
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
   if(Serial.available() > 0){
      int inc = Serial.ParseInt();
      inc = pow(inc,2);
      Serial.println(inc);
   }
}
```

And here is my RPI code:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.axis([0,20,0,400])
plt.ion()
plt.show()

for i in range(20):
   ser.write(str(i))
   y=int(ser.readline())
   plt.scatte([i],[y],'bo')
   plt.draw()
```

Everything seems to work completely fine in the loop, but I keep getting an error message saying "Type Error: Not implemented for this type" referring to the 'plt.draw()' function

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you have a chance, could you include the full traceback?  It's difficult to spot the error without more information.  (Also, you have a typo in your plotting example, should be `plt.scatter`. That's not the source of your problem, though.)

Answer (score 4):

It is because you are calling `plt.scatter` with `'bo'` inside.

**The above works only for `plt.plot` !!** i.e. specifying both the marker style and colour together.

Whereas for `plt.scatter` you should instead call it this way:

```
plt.scatter([i],[y],c='b',marker='o')
```

This will work!